# How to include a link in the text?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I'd like to share a link in a comment/question/answer hiding the link to some paper and showing instead the title, how can one do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a markdown reference http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: This is also described in editing help in the part about [links](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is [a link to the parent site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), which I created by inputting `[a link to the parent site](https://math.stackexchange.com/)`.

Comment: @Issac. Your answer doesn't help that much cos it's not self explanatory. I think you should give a step by step answer for new comers who are not yet experienced using the website